# How to Convert this to array of integer values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
[["1"], ["10"], ["7"], ["5"], ["1"], ["1"], ["8"], ["2"], ["2"], ["5"], ["10"]]
```

Output required is:

```
[1, 10, 7, 5, 1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 5, 10]
```

I am trying to convert this to the array of integer's
but I am unable to do this.

Code I have tried is:

```
arr=[["1"], ["10"], ["7"], ["5"], ["1"], ["1"], ["8"], ["2"], ["2"], ["5"], ["10"]]
arr_intvalues=arr.flatten     #["1", "10", "7", "5", "1", "1", "8", "2", "2", "5", "10"]
```

Comment: This is "first 5 minutes of the tutorial" stuff. You'll be better served by learning Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do:

```
arr.flatten.map(&:to_i)
```